# Aggregate functions in QGIS using spatial intersection

Tags: qgis, aggregation

I am trying to compute a virtual filed using aggregate functions in QGIS (3.6). I want to compute the average on a field in the child layer based on the spatial intersection with the parent layer. Using qgis_sample data for testing and modifying from the example given in the tool I wrote:

```
aggregate( 'airports', 'mean', 'ELEV', intersects( $geometry, geometry(@parent) ) )
```

It does not seem to work and only gives NULL back. The goal is to compute the mean on a given field in the child layer (airport) aggregating by spatial intersection with the parent layer (regions), is this allowed/possible with aggregate function?

I've also looked into mean aggregate function by it seems to me that it doesn't accept geometry intersection either for the filter or the group by clause. Or perhaps I am missing the right syntax for it but the documentation is limited.

Comment: Will you check how your syntax works if you change 'ELEV' to "ELEV" ? (single to double quotes)

Comment: I tested the expression following @Kazuhito's suggestion, and got it to work with the field name in double quotes or without any quotes. It won't work with the field name in single quotes because it doesn't understand that it's a field name, so it just tries to evaluate the string 'ELEV', which is a valid expression for the mean function.

Comment: Oops, typo. I meant that 'ELEV' is **not** a valid expression for the mean function.

Comment: Many thanks, it did work indeed, I am still a bit puzzled by the syntax though, as I had previously tested the expression `aggregate( 'airports', 'count', 'fid', 
intersects( $geometry, geometry(@parent) ) )` which worked just fine even with single quotes. Is this different behavior linked to the function 'mean'? In other words, is it due to the fact that ELEV is also a valid expression for mean function as pointed out by @csk?

Comment: That's surprising. Maybe the `count` function *assumes* that its input expression is a field name, whereas the `mean` function does not. That's what it seems like from your description, but I wouldn't have predicted that.